# How to empty the content of a key belonging to an associative array without unsetting the key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've an array titled `$aFilter` as follows(Output of `print_r($aFilter);`):

Currently only one internal array element is shown but it can contain many such elements. So consider the case with multiple internal array elements.

```
Array(    
          [0] => Array(            
            [filter_id] => 84            
            [user_id] => 984            
            [item_id] => 244            
            [type_id] => user        
            [feed_type] => a:10:{s:5:\"pages\";i:1;s:5:\"photo\";i:1;s:4:\"link\";i:1;s:5:\"event\";i:1;s:6:
\"friend\";i:1;s:11:\"user_status\";i:1;s:4:\"poll\";i:1;s:4:\"quiz\";i:1;s:6:\"market\";i:1;s:4:\"apps
\";i:1;}            
            [get_noti] => 0            
            [time_stamp] => 1432271245        
          )
        )
```

I want the following desired array :

```
Array(    
          [0] => Array(            
            [filter_id] => 84            
            [user_id] => 984            
            [item_id] => 244            
            [type_id] => user        
            [feed_type] =>             
            [get_noti] => 0            
            [time_stamp] => 1432271245        
          )
        )
```

So I tried following code but it returned me the same array upon `print_r($aFilter);`

```
$aFilter['feed_type'] = '';
```

Why so? Can someone please help me in my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You dont want that key or you need it to be null?

Comment: @sgtBOSE : I want the key to be present but it should contain nothing. The current content present within key ['feed_type'] should be emptied from all such internal array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
array_walk( $aFilter, function(&$var){
    $var['feed_type'] = '';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `null` to it -

```
$aFilter[0]['feed_type'] = null; // You can set '' this also but would prefer null
```

**Update**

If you have multiple inner array -

```
array_walk ( $aFilter, function (&$key) { $key["feed_type"] = null; } );
```

Comment: But what if there are multiple such inner array elements? Your code will work only for first inner array element.

Comment: Then you have to loop through it. It is just the solution for the OP's condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
foreach($aFilter as $aFilterRow)
{
    $aFilterRow['feed_type'] = "";
}
```

Comment: Because it is an associative array. If it has only one row you can directly do with $aFilter[0]['feed_type'] = "";

Answer (score 0):

Your array is two dimensional array

so use like the below example:

```
$aFilter[0]['feed_type'] = '';
```

**Edited**

```
foreach($aFilter as $aFilt)
{
    $aFilt['feed_type'] = '';
}
```

Comment: But what if there are multiple such inner array elements? Your code will work only for first inner array element.

Answer (score 0):

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) should help you. Try this:

```
function removeFeedType(&$arr)
{
    $arr['feed_type'] = null;
}
array_walk($aField, 'removeFeedType');
```